# Why do the maximum of the value change when I use set null function in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator

[image: screenshot]
I want to set null to the value<=0 using the raster calculator in ArcMap, but after that, I got a new raster with a changed maximum value. Is there any problem with my setting? How to keep the other value (e.g. maximum value) the same but set null to value<=0? please see the attached screenshot.

Comment: Con(raster >0, raster)

Comment: Statistics of original may have been approximate. You can run calculate statistics tool on original to check.

Comment: @user2856 Sorry, I may not understand what you mentioned. Could you describe it in more detail? Thank you so much.  Actually, I mosaic two MODIS images into one and covert the original format(.hdf) to the new one (.tiff). And then I used the new one to do the raster calculator.

Comment: @FelixIP the result of Con(raster >0, raster) is the same as that of SetNull(raster <=0, raster)

Comment: @user2856 what is the difference between the calculate statistics tool and ArcToolbox?

Comment: @user2856 Thank you for your reply but is what I am doing not the same as what you mention? Is the raster calculator not the calculate statistics tool?

Comment: @user2856 Thank you! I got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the [Calculate Statistics](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-statistics.htm) tool on your original raster.

This is to ensure that the raster statistics (min, max, stdev etc) are correct, not approximate. You should never rely on the min/max values displayed in the layer legend in the table of contents, they can be approximate (derived from a sample).